# Difference between sexual and asexual spore

Tags: botany, reproduction

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore) Wikipedia article on Spores mentions this:

> In biology, a spore is a unit of sexual or asexual reproduction that may be adapted for ....

What is the difference between the *sexual spore* and *asexual spore*? 
Are they any different on basis of formation, diploid or haploid, role in life cycle?

By *Sexual Spores*, I mean the spores that arise in the sexual reproduction process and similarly for *Asexual Spores*, i.e. spores which arise in asexual reproduction process.

To add to the context, this image shows the Sexual and Asexual spores in a certain fungi (Mycelium) life cycle.

[image: Sexual and Asexual spores in Fungi Mycelium]

Comment: I am curious - if this is for an assignment, are you not given sources that contain what your teacher thinks you should learn?  Or are students just turned loose on the internet now?

Comment: @Willk this is not an assignment given by anyone to me. I was in fact studying reproduction in organisms and dug into 'spores', eventually I ended up upon the Wikipedia page on Spore (link mentioned in the question). And was curious between their difference. [I have edited the question now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same wikipedia page of [spores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spore#Classification_of_spore-producing_organisms) you cited, you can find that they have said:

> Fungi commonly produce spores, as a result of sexual, or asexual, reproduction. Spores are usually haploid..

Again,

> Vascular plant spores are always haploid.

So, sexual and asexual spores have no difference in ploidy- both are **haploid**. (There are exceptions- [zygospores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygospore) in fungi are diploid)
Now, coming to mode of formation, they are different. For example, in [Ascomycetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascomycota), sexual *ascospores* are produced endogenously whereas asexual *conidiospores* are produced exogenously.

Spores that are formed by the process of **meiosis** are sexual spores and when formed from mitosis are asexual. The term 'sexual' means meiosis is involved.